# What is this rule of inference called?

Tags: logic

Let *P*, *Q*, *R* be three statements. Is there a name for the following rule of inference?

> If *P* implies *Q*, and if *P* implies *R*, then *P* implies both *Q* and *R*.

Comment: Just for clarity's sake, do you mean for your conclusion to be `P -> Q & R` (i.e. how the "and" operator works), or do you mean something more like `P -> Q,R` (i.e. multiple consequents)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R&W in their landmark work in formal logic : [Principia Mathematica](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/principia-mathematica/), [page 110](https://books.google.it/books?id=ke9yGmFy24sC&pg=PA110), called it "Principle of Composition" :

> if a proposition implies each of two propositions, then it implies their
>   logical product. This is called by Peano the "principle of composition."

The reference is to [Giuseppe Peano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuseppe_Peano); see e.g. [Logique mathématique (1897)](https://books.google.it/books?id=AydPAAAAYAAJ).

Comment: Did the phrase “principle of composition” enter into general use? I found an apparently related idea on SEP at “Propositional Dynamic Logic” > Hoare calculus. Otherwise I have not been able to find the phrase. The most typical search result is “fallacy of composition”. I was able to find several references to Distribution as a rule of equivalence. E.g., math SE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318235/distribution-axiom-of-modal-logic

Comment: @Mark Andrews - I do not think so... but there is no reason to expect that every tautology has a name.

Answer (score 1):

> If P implies Q, and if P implies R, then P implies both Q and R.

The name of the rule is *Distribution*. *See* Barker, Stephen (1965), *The elements of logic*, p. 124-25 (Truth-functional principles for use in deduction).

Comment: The question asks for the *name* of this rule of inference.

Comment: In short, the name is Distribution. But it takes the two steps to show why distribution works.